# Filter 2 lists over one pass (log(N) complexity)

Tags: python

I have two lists similar to these (equal length and populated with `string` values):

```
a = ["W", "", "X", "", "Y", "Z"]
b = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

I want to remove the elements from list `a`, if the element is an empty `string`. In addition, I want to remove corresponding elements from the `b` list (with same index). So the desired resulting lists for the example above would be:

```
a = ["W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
b = ["a", "c", "e", "f"]
```

I can do this with a couple of `for` loops but I wonder if it can be done in a more efficient way (list comprehensions)? The reason for this is that I'm working with very large lists (~ 4.5 million elements) and efficiency is critical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `zip()` to transform your data twice:

```
>>> a, b = zip(*((av, bv) for av, bv in zip(a,b) if av))
>>> a
('W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z')
>>> b
('a', 'c', 'e', 'f')
```

Comment: Can you briefly explain how to read that line? I see that you're unpacking with zip(*()), but what is happening inside those brackets?

Comment: @BourbonCreams it’s a generator expression, a bit like a list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ["W", "", "X", "", "Y", "Z"]
b = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

aNew,bNew = zip(*[(a[i], b[i]) for i in range(len(a)) if len(a[i]) > 0])

print(aNew) 
#('W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z')
print(bNew)
#('a', 'c', 'e', 'f')
```